# I don't have greater and smaller keys

Tags: keyboard, laptop, german

I have a German keyboard and I want to write "<" and ">" to code but my Laptop doesn´t have these keys. The only solution I found was "‹" and "›" but this doesn´t work in vscode.

What can I do?

Comment: Please do some basic research. If you google "linux remap keys" it gives you all sorts of options. Also, what desktop environment are you using? You can almost certainly choose a German keyboard layout through the DE's system settings, which should put the <> keys in the bottom left

Answer (score 0):

Without the brand & model, it's hard to tell (laptops manufacturer sometimes use silly keyboard layouts)...

Anyway, the Unicode are respectively u+003c and u+003e (compose it with `[left CTRL]+[shift]+u` then type the character's code).
That's a makeshift solution, though, and if you have a lot to code (especially HTML), you'll get mad before Monday!